# How to count application clicks

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, odbc

Application launcher help needed,

I would like to track each click a user make to launch a program and have the info collected in a database, (txt/odbc) for review at a later date or output to anther program

Application Name:
Clicks:

Here is the code my application launcher uses to start a new program:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\notepad.exe")
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

I am very new to Programming.

Thanks your for your help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you asking how to track how often your application is executed? Or clicks in the application? As it is your question is not very clear, but could definitely be improved. Do you have some code that you're tried for the purpose of "have the info collected in a database" ?

Comment: so want store `count` in a `table` ?

Comment: yes a table or Text file which ever would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Having a sub like this

```
Private Sub WriteData(_text As String, _where As String)
    Dim w As New System.IO.StreamWriter(_where)
    w.Write(_text)
    w.Close()
End Sub
```

and a global variable like

```
Private Counter as Integer = 0
```

you can save some data to a text file.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\notepad.exe")
    Counter += 1
    WriteData(Counter.ToString, "C:\TEMP.TXT")
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

You need to add the following line to the top of your page (to be able to use `StreamWriter`)

```
Imports System.IO
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have done everything like our comments. Please try the code bellow:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Counter As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Private _whereDirectory As String = "C:\TEMP\"
    Private _where As String = _whereDirectory & "LOG.TXT"

    Private Sub WriteData()
        If Not IO.Directory.Exists(_whereDirectory) Then
            IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(_whereDirectory)
        End If
        'Write data when something is clicked
        Dim w As New System.IO.StreamWriter(_where)
        For Each item In Counter
            w.WriteLine(item.Key & ":" & item.Value)
        Next
        w.Close()
    End Sub

    Sub ReadData()
        'Read the log when the program starts
        Dim r As New System.IO.StreamReader(_where)
        Dim line As String = r.ReadLine()
        While Not line Is Nothing
            Dim items() As String = line.Replace(" ", "").Split(":")
            If items.Count = 2 AndAlso IsNumeric(items(1)) Then
                Try
                    Counter.Add(items(0), CInt(items(1)))
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            End If
            line = r.ReadLine
        End While
        r.Close()
    End Sub

    Sub UserClicked(_what As String)
        'Increment the counter
        If Counter.ContainsKey(_what) Then
            Counter(_what) += 1
        Else
            Counter.Add(_what, 1)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btNotepad_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btNotepad.Click
        'Clicking on notepad button
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Notepad.exe")
        UserClicked("Notepad")
        WriteData()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btIE_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btIE.Click
        'Clicking on IE button
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore", "http://www.google.com")
        UserClicked("IE")
        WriteData()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ReadData()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The result is a text file like bellow:

```
Notepad:2 
IE:2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried inserting your code into my app, but its giving me a build error. once I remove your code the build completes.

Comment: Error 2 ')' expected.

Comment: Error 1 'StreamWriter' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Adds `Imports System.IO` at the top of the page

Comment: I can't figure out where ) could be missing. Please add the imports line and let me know if you are getting another error.

Comment: That stopped the error, and your code works. however i wanted the code to count the clicks... 1, 2, 3, not to notify when that a link was clicked.            

Application Name:
Clicks:

Comment: I don't know what you need me to verify, I am new on this site.

Comment: The edition I have made in my answer. Is that you want?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the changes, I tested it and the count (#) shows up, but it remains at one not matter how many times i click it

Comment: You need to declare the Counter variable outside the sub. Right after the declaration of the Form. Have you done it?

Comment: I have a question, we plan on having 6 apps contributing to (C:\TEMP.TXT) file. Example

Program: NotePad - 10 Clicks
Program: WordPad - 5 Clicks
and so on

Comment: Ok. It is a different question. You need to have a dictionary. Declare a variable as counterPro as New Dictionary(Of String, Integer). Then on button click set counterPro("Notepad") = counterPro("Notepad") + 1

Comment: Just remember you need to initialize the dictionary as counterPro.Add("Notepad",1) on the first click of Notepad.

Comment: Thank you very much I will give it a try in the morning its 3:06 Am Here. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok. It is 4:07 here. Tomorrow I edit my answer to solve your case. Good night.

Comment: I have edited the answer. I believe everything is working fine now.